# Python Selenium webscraping returns no data using XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Tried to scrape data from a webpage.  After login to the site, in the developer tools able to search the xpath and find the match.  But, paython code is not returning the data.

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlite3 import Time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import zerodhacred

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/SPILLAIP/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get(loginURL)

nifty_bank_values_xpath = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'pane-legend-item-value__main')]")
    print("Len of nifty_bank_values_xpath: ",len(nifty_bank_values_xpath))
```

The output is

> 

d:\My Personal\2022\Suresh\Learning\Python\zerodha.py:27: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass
in a Service object
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/SPILLAIP/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57153/devtools/browser/74a90941-a12f-4be4-b12a-01b256292a5f
[15120:6400:0309/123030.129:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [12:30:30.129] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[15120:6400:0309/123030.137:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [12:30:30.136] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
Len of nifty_bank_values_xpath:  0

> 

similarly, when tried with find_element

```
nifty_bank_values_xpath = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'pane-legend-item-value__main')]")
```

Getting following error:

> 

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(@class, 'pane-legend-item-value__main')]"}
(Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.51)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

> 

Able to find the data in the Dev Tools->Elements returning 6 matches.

image [image: Developer Tools indicates matching rows]

html captured from dev console

```
<body class="app-wrapper">
   <noscript><strong>We're sorry but kite doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>
   <div id="app" class="app mobile page-tvchart">
      <div class="header">
         <div class="wrapper">
            <!----> 
            <div class="header-right">
               <!----> <!----> 
               <div class="app-nav mobile"><a href="/marketwatch" class=""><span class="icon icon-bookmark"></span></a> <a href="/dashboard" class=""><span class="icon icon-compass"></span></a> <a href="/orders" class=""><span class="icon icon-book"></span></a> <a href="/holdings" class=""><span class="icon icon-briefcase"></span></a> <a href="/positions" class=""><span class="icon icon-file-text"></span></a> <a href="/funds" class="margins"><span class="icon icon-credit-card"></span></a></div>
               <div class="right-nav">
                  <div class="user-nav perspective">
                     <a href="" class="dropdown-label">
                        <div id="avatar-43">
                           <div class="avatar" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; border-radius: 50%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.1); font-size: 9px; font-weight: 300; color: rgb(156, 39, 176); line-height: 26px;"><span>SS</span></div>
                           <!---->
                        </div>
                        <span class="user-id">ZX8487</span>
                     </a>
                     <!---->
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container wrapper">
         <!----> 
         <div class="container-right">
            <!----> <!----> 
            <div class="page-content tvchart">
               <!----> 
               <div>
                  <div class="chart-frame">
                     <div id="tv_chart_container" class="tv-chart-container" style="height: 547px;"><iframe id="tradingview_e1a6c" name="tradingview_e1a6c" src="/static/tv-chart/static/en-tv-chart.aaac22e21df68f2f7bad.html#symbol=NIFTY%20BANK%3AINDICES%3A260105&amp;interval=1D&amp;widgetbar=%7B%22details%22%3Afalse%2C%22watchlist%22%3Afalse%2C%22watchlist_settings%22%3A%7B%22default_symbols%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D&amp;timeFrames=%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%225y%22%2C%22resolution%22%3A%22W%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%221y%22%2C%22resolution%22%3A%22W%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%226m%22%2C%22resolution%22%3A%22120%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%223m%22%2C%22resolution%22%3A%2260%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%221m%22%2C%22resolution%22%3A%2230%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%225d%22%2C%22resolution%22%3A%225%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%221d%22%2C%22resolution%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D&amp;locale=en&amp;uid=tradingview_e1a6c&amp;clientId=tradingview.com&amp;userId=ZX8487&amp;chartsStorageUrl=%2Fapi%2Fchart%2Fpreferences&amp;chartsStorageVer=1.1&amp;customCSS=%2Fstatic%2Ftv-chart%2Fstatic%2Fcustom_style.css&amp;debug=false&amp;timezone=Asia%2FKolkata&amp;theme=Light" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="instrument-market-data">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="three columns">
                           <div class="label">Open</div>
                           <div class="value">33278.9</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="three columns">
                           <div class="label">High</div>
                           <div class="value">33890.9</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="three columns">
                           <div class="label">Low</div>
                           <div class="value">32948.9</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="three columns">
                           <div class="label">Close</div>
                           <div class="value">33158.1</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="three columns">
                           <div class="label">Volume</div>
                           <div class="value">—</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="three columns">
                           <div class="label">Avg. trade price</div>
                           <div class="value">—</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="three columns">
                           <div class="label">Total buy quantity</div>
                           <div class="value">—</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="three columns">
                           <div class="label">Total sell quantity</div>
                           <div class="value">—</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!---->
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!----> <!----> 
      <div class="baskets">
         <!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> <!---->
      </div>
      <!----> 
      <div>
         <!----> <!---->
      </div>
      <!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> 
      <div class="orders-basket">
         <!---->
      </div>
      <!----> <!---->
   </div>
   <script async="">try {
      var theme = JSON.parse(localStorage.__storejs_kite_theme);
      if (theme) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", theme);
      }
      } catch (_) {
      }
   </script><script type="module" src="/static/js/chunk-vendors.ea6114a1.js"></script><script type="module" src="/static/js/app.ae4bb317.js"></script><script>!function(){var e=document,t=e.createElement("script");if(!("noModule"in t)&&"onbeforeload"in t){var n=!1;e.addEventListener("beforeload",function(e){if(e.target===t)n=!0;else if(!e.target.hasAttribute("nomodule")||!n)return;e.preventDefault()},!0),t.type="module",t.src=".",e.head.appendChild(t),t.remove()}}();</script><script src="/static/js/chunk-vendors-legacy.ea6114a1.js" nomodule=""></script><script src="/static/js/app-legacy.cffeb71c.js" nomodule=""></script>
   <div class="su-toast-groups">
      <div class="su-toast-group su-toast-top-left">
         <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="su-toast-group su-toast-top-center">
         <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="su-toast-group su-toast-top-right">
         <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="su-toast-group su-toast-bottom-left">
         <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="su-toast-group su-toast-bottom-center">
         <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="su-toast-group su-toast-bottom-right">
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!---->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `wait` here.
You should wait for the elements to be completely loaded before accessing them with `find_elements` methods.
The best approach here is to use Expected Conditions explicit waits, as following:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from sqlite3 import Time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import zerodhacred

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/SPILLAIP/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
browser.get(loginURL)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'pane-legend-item-value__main')]")))
time.sleep(0.3) #short pause added to make sure that all the relevant elements are loaded, not only the first one
nifty_bank_values_xpath = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'pane-legend-item-value__main')]")
print("Len of nifty_bank_values_xpath: ",len(nifty_bank_values_xpath))
```

**UPD**
Since that element is inside an iframe you have to switch to that iframe before accessing elements inside it, as following:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from sqlite3 import Time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import zerodhacred

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/SPILLAIP/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
browser.get(loginURL)
wait).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='tradingview']")))

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'pane-legend-item-value__main')]")))
time.sleep(0.3) #short pause added to make sure that all the relevant elements are loaded, not only the first one
nifty_bank_values_xpath = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'pane-legend-item-value__main')]")
print("Len of nifty_bank_values_xpath: ",len(nifty_bank_values_xpath))
```

When you finished working with elements inside the iframe, to switch to default content you will need to perform

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Added code

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'pane-legend-item-value__main')]")))
    time.sleep(2)

still unable to find the elements.

Comment: If open the Developer Tool, able to find using same XPATH

Comment: can you share a link to that page or at least ALL the page HTML?

Comment: URL is https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/web/tvc/INDICES/NIFTY%20BANK/260105  This URL needs credentials.

Comment: Tried to copy the html to the original question in the end for your review.  Not sure if this is complete

Comment: I can't find elements matching `pane-legend-item-value__main` class name in the HTML you provided here

Comment: Possible, as I said this is only a possible grab.  On elements tab I am able to view, see the screen shot provided.

Comment: OK, can you check if that element is inside an iframe? maybe out of the visible screen?

Comment: Yes, it is under <iframe id="tradingview....

Comment: if so you have to switch to that iframe. I will update the answer

Comment: I have used the iframe id as you gave me. In case it is more complex please update the locator correspondingly

Comment: Tried with 
browser.get(niftybankchartURL)
time.sleep(10)

# jump into iframe
browser.switch_to.frame("tradingview_8634c")

time.sleep(10)

No luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Prophet for guiding me to explore `iframe`.

```
browser.get(niftybankchartURL)
time.sleep(10)

# jump into iframe
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
```

Once the `switch_to` into the frame the `XPATH` was working fine.

Comment: I'm happy I could help you, but please remove this since it's not an answer to your question.